# Find sum of n largest elements online

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am solving a problem but I got stuck on this part.

There are 3 types of query: add a element (integer), remove a element, get sum of n (*n* can be any integer) largest elements. How can I do this efficient ? I am current use this solution: add a element , remove a element (binary search, *O(lg n)* ). getSum (naive, O(n) ).

Answer (score 3):

A segment tree is commonly used to find the [sum of a given range](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-sum-of-given-range/). Building that on top of a binary search tree should get the data structure you are looking for with `O(log N)` adds, remove and sum given range. By querying sum over the range where the k-largest elements are (roughly `N-k to N`), you can get the sum of the k-largest elements in `O(log N)`. The result being a mutable ordered segment tree rather than the standard immutable (static) unordered one.

Basically, you just add variables to hold the number of children and the sum of their values to each parent node and use that information to find the sum via `O(log N)` additions and/or subtractions.

If `k` is fixed, you can use the same approach that allows for `O(1)` find-min/max in heaps to allow for `O(1)` find the k-largest elements sum simply by updating a variable holding the value during each `O(log N)` add/remove.

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on the relative frequency of the queries but if we assume a typical situation where the sum query will be much more frequent than the add-remove requests (and add is more frequent than remove), the solution is to store a tuple of the sums and the numbers.

So the first element will be (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>), the second element in your list will be (a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>+a<sub>2</sub>) and so on. (Note that when you insert a new element in the k-th position, you still don't need to do the whole sum, just add the new number to the preceding element's sum.)

Removals will be quite expensive though but that's the trade-off for an O(1) sum query.